# How do I send data from MySQL database connected to a Node.js server so that I can use it for client side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

To preface, I'm completely new to NodeJs and MySQL.

I have a website running on Node with express like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var mysql = require("mysql");

app.use(express.static('Script'));

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password", 
    database: "blocks"
});

con.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("connected!");
    con.query("SELECT * FROM blockchain", function(err, result, fields){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
 });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});


app.listen(8080);
```

It's connected to the server successfully, and can print out the server values on my command prompt.

Is there a way to send this data to my website such that I can use the values for client side scripting? For example, I want a create a new `<p>` element in my `index.html` file to represent every entry in the database, and thus alter my websites displayed information.

So if the database was empty, my website would look empty. If the database had three entries, my website would have 3 `<p>` elements that corresponded to the inputs of the three entries.

Answer (score -1):

To easy. At first we open the db connections:

```
 con.connect(function(err){
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log("connected!");
```

Then if the connection is set up, we can start answering requests:

```
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
```

Now when a request comes in, we get the latest data from the db:

```
      con.query("SELECT * FROM blockchain", function(err, result, fields){
         if(err) return res.end("sth went wrong :(");
         res.end(result);
     });
   });
 });
```

Now you only need to transfer the data into html, for that i would recommend using a template engine.

Answer (score -1):

When you query data from a database, it is an asyncronous operation. In other words, it takes time before you have all the data.
So in your case it sounds best to use a promise:

```
 var mysql = require('promise-mysql');
mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'sauron',
    password: 'theonetruering',
    database: 'mordor'
}).then(function(conn){
    var result = conn.query('select `name` from hobbits');
    conn.end();
    return result;
}).then(function(rows){
      for (var i in rows){
          document.write("<p>name[i]</p>");
      }
});
```

The funtion after .then executes when your query has finished. Now you can sort you query with a for loop.

mysql-promise: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql

HTML DOM write: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp